# NSData encoding

Tags: swift, nsstringencoding, cfstring

Currently, I'm trying to parse an `NSData` in my iOS app. Problem is, I can't seem to find a proper hebrew encoding for parsing. I must decode the data using the `Windows-1255` encoding (hebrew encoding type for windows) or `ISO 8859-8` encoding, or I'll get plain gibberish. The closest I've got to solving the issue was using

```
CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.ISOLatinHebrew)
```

yet it throws `'CFStringEncodings' is not convertible to 'CFStringEncoding'` (notice Encoding**s** vs Encoding).

What can I do in order to encode the data correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `CFStringEncodings` is an enumeration based on `CFIndex`
(which in turn is a type alias for `Int`), whereas `CFStringEncoding` is a type
alias for `UInt32`. Therefore you have to convert the `.ISOLatinHebrew` 
value explicitly to a `CFStringEncoding`:

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.ISOLatinHebrew
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to get my hands a bit dirty. 
I saw that `CFStringEncodings` has a relation to the file `CFStringEncodingsExt.h`, so I searched the file for some help. Suddenly I came across a huge `CF_ENUM` that included exactly what I needed- all of the `CFStringEncodings` by their `UInt32` value!

So it has turned out that `kCFStringEncodingISOLatinHebrew = 0x0208, /* ISO 8859-8 */`

I encourage everyone who is facing this encoding issue to go to that file and search for his needed encoding.