# How to change GB-2312 encoding to UTF-8

Tags: swift, utf-8, gb2312

I use `nsurlsession` and received nsdata with GB-2312 encoding. How can I change the encoding from GB-2312 to UTF-8.

I tried this code

```
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000)
var result = NSString(data: data, encoding:enc)!
```

but it has an error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000'

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/27862477/1187415 and replace `ISOLatinHebrew` by `GB_18030_2000` ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue with using the concrete value of gb312 constant instead of the apple defined constant

```
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(0x0632);     
let dogString:String = NSString(data: data, encoding: enc)!
println(dogString)
```

---

here is the better solution - and thanks for Daij-Djan's suggestion

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))
let dogString:String = NSString(data: data, encoding: enc)!
```

Comment: bad solution - don't use magic numbers -- do what martin R wrote